Flex Scanner continuously running after implementing steps from authoritative book
I'm on Linux Ubuntu.
I'm reimplementing the Flex scanner example provided at page 5 of "Managing projects with GNU make" by ROBERT MECKLENBURG.
count_words.c (application source code):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern int fee_count, fie_count, foe_count, fum_count; 
extern int yylex( void ); 

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
 yylex();
 printf( "%d %d %d %d\n", fee_count, fie_count, foe_count, fum_count );
 exit( 0 );
}

lexer.l (input file of the Flex scanner):
        int fee_count = 0;
        int fie_count = 0;
        int foe_count = 0;
        int fum_count = 0;

%%
fee fee_count++;
fie fie_count++;
foe foe_count++;
fum fum_count++;

Makefile:
count_words: count_words.o lexer.o -lfl
 gcc count_words.o lexer.o -lfl -ocount_words
count_words.o: count_words.c
 gcc -c count_words.c
lexer.o: lexer.c
 gcc -c lexer.c
lexer.c: lexer.l
 flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c

Proper tabs are inserted before each command.
Not pasting lexer.c because it's huge but here's a link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lN7Jr93xa5hVKIHtCZgXmGRy1u3x4eE3/view?usp=sharing
When I run ./count_words This is a test fue , I get a blank output as if there was an infinite loop.
What is wrong?
I checked that Flex is installed. It is:
$which flex
/usr/bin/flex

I checked that libfl.a is installed. It is:
libfl-dev/jammy,now 2.6.4-8build2 amd64 [installed]
  static library for flex (a fast lexical analyzer generator)

I did notice that the book forgets to include stdlib.h for exit() and did include it.
I tried to find issues in lexer.c but the file is too complicated for me.
The book later recommends to append the following lines to lexer.l:
.
\n

I tried it but it does not solve the problem (no surprise).

Not sure if it's relevant but your makefile looks a bit odd. -lfl probably shouldn't be a dependency and -ocount_words should be -o count_words (note the space).

Also, doesn't yylex read from stdin by default?  If so your executable is blocking reading from its standard input.

@G.M. Your comment regarding stdin solved the issue.

If you specify -lfl as a dependency make will try to create/update a file named -lfl based on any rules it finds -- so I'm surprised the build succeeds.  Re. stdin: it sounds like you really need to brush up on your C before going any further.  Try echo 'This is a test fue' | ./count_words .

@G.M. I was also surprised to see -lfl as a dependency in the Makefile. But that's what the author does in the book (page 5) if my reading is correct: https://github.com/Vauteck/docs_utils/blob/master/autotools/Oreilly%20-%20Managing%20Projects%20With%20Gnu%20Make%203Rd%20Edition.pdf

@G.M. Excerpt of the book regarding this: "Finally, make examines -lfl. The -l option to gcc indicates a system library that must be linked into the application. The actual library name indicated by “fl” is libfl.a. GNU make includes special support for this syntax. When a prerequisite of the forml is seen, make searches for a file of the form libNAME.so; if no match is found, it then searches for libNAME.a. Here make finds /usr/lib/libfl.a and proceeds with the final action, linking."

Sorry, my mistake.  I'd forgotten about the support for library dependencies.

@G.M., specifying -lfl as a dependency will make GNU make to interpret a dependency on libfl.{so,a}, which probably will result in a make error as not finding the library.  This is a GNU make feature (you can consult it on gmake doc)  Anyway, he should have received a complaint about being unable to create libfl.a or similar.  But makefile spec is not related to the problem, anyway.
